# units of screen in chrome developer mode

Tags: css, google-chrome, resolution

I am using the chrome developer to see how the web look in device.
I am confusing about this

[image]

what is the  unit of the screen numbers? this is not px..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen numbers are in pixel only. Check this out here - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

[image]